# override standard style with ABS

Tags: android, android-layout

In my AndroidManifest file i do not declare a theme.
The result is:
black background and ABS with blue background, also states of list item's is blue.
thats fine.

now i want to make to set the `indeterminateProgressStyle` to `Widget.ProgressBar.Small`

Therefore i have to declare my own style like this:

```
<style name="Custom" parent="??">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarIPS</item>
</style>
```

what should i enter in the parent parameter?
i want all style behaviors like before (black background with blue ABS and blue list item states etc as it is defined when i dont declare a theme attribute in AndroidManifest.

EDIT:
i also need to know this parent's value:

```
<style name="ActionBarIPS" parent="ABS with blue background">
    <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item>
</style>
```

the version without a style in manifest:
[image: the version without a style in manifest]

the version with custom style and parent=Theme.Sherlock
[image: the version with custom style and parent=Theme.Sherlock]

i want the first version with indeterminate spinner set to "small"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depend to your current style, It can be `Theme.Sherlock`, `Theme.Sherlock.Light`, `Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow` and etc, e.g:

```
<style name="Custom" parent="Theme.Sherlock or Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarIPS</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/IndeterminateProgress</item>
</style>
```

***Note:*** You must declare this style in `style.xml` in your `values` directory.

**Edited:**

You got blue `ActionBar` without using ABS because you're using Samsung `TouchWiz` default UI.

If you install your `APK` in non-samsung devices you won't see this blue action bar, But If you are forced to have blue actionbar then put the following image in your `drawable` directory and set it as your actionbar background through:

```
 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.TouchWiz_ActionBar_Bg));
```

[image]

Comment: i don't mentioned it: i tried to put set parent to `Theme.Sherlock` but the result was: ABS was in black style too and not in standard blue style

Comment: @micho Are you looking for light style?

Comment: i don't know which style has which color, if i do not declare any style the standard ABS has blue background and the "content area" has black background. i need to know which style it is to fill out the correct in parent to get the exact same.

Comment: @micho There are only two kinds of styles in holo mode, First one is `Holo Light` which equals to `Theme.Sherlock.Light` in `ActionBarSherlock` and the second one is `Holo Dark` that equals to `Theme.Sherlock`, for more information check [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/themes.html) link. Did you add the above style in your android manifest?

Comment: thank you. yes i added it in my manifest. my problem is, that the background is of ABS is black. i think there must be a style where it is blue but i can't find it or is it inherited from another theme?#

Comment: @micho Use `Theme.Sherlock.Light` instead.

Comment: i don't know what i'm doing wrong. when i use `Theme.Sherlock.Light`the ABS and all backgrounds are white or light grey (don't know). one more try :) when i didn't use the Theme attribute in manifest i use the default style. this default style has black background, only the ABS has blue background. so that's perfect but now i want to override the indeterminateProgressStyle and set the loading spinner to `small`. but at all your suggestions i get a black or a white (light grey) background on ABS, i don't want that, i want the default style. how can i achieve that?

Comment: :) when i try your solution, the ABS has black background with Theme.Sherlock and not blue like the default behavior (if i don't declare any style in manifest). also the theme isn't exact the same as without style declaration.

Comment: @micho Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: @micho Np, We're here to help each other - Check my updated answer, Hope this help you :-).

Comment: where can this image be found?

Comment: @micho You can create a 9 patch image with Photoshop according your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Theme.Sherlock" as a parent. Also I suggest to add:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarIPS</item>
```